# Java matrix libraries

Tags: java, matrix, colt

I was wondering whether any of the well-known matrix libraries for Java, such as Colt or EJML, actually provide similar functionality as MatLab? For instance, I can't seem to find anywhere in the definition of their API simple method to add or subtract two matrices/vectors by each other, which seems to be the most common operation used. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try Apache Commons Math library. org.apache.commons.math3.linear package contains the functions that you want. [Home page](http://commons.apache.org/math/)

Comment: Yes, but that is probably less efficient then Colt or EJML

Answer (score 42):

Some Java libraries for linear algebra are:

- Apache Commons Math: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/
- jeigen - a wrapper for eigen - https://github.com/hughperkins/jeigen (includes complex and rarely found feature like matrix exponential and matrix logarithm)
- jblas http://mikiobraun.github.io/jblas/ (also features more complex functions like matrix exponential, also very fast).
- Colt http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/
- JAMA http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/
- UJMP - http://sourceforge.net/projects/ujmp/

**EDIT** maybe we can extend this list whenever one comes across and you know - the world keeps moving:

- ojAlgo - http://ojalgo.org/ has promising benchmarks
- Efficient Java Matrix Library (EJML) - http://ejml.org
- ParallelColt - https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/parallelcolt
- la4j - http://la4j.org/
- MTJ - https://github.com/fommil/matrix-toolkits-java
- nd4j - https://nd4j.org/ lets you choose underlying native implementations like cuda or openBlas

*Note:* Personally: I use Apache Commons Math and Colt in my own project (http://www.finmath.net). While commons math is actively developed, I found that Colt is still faster in some tasks (like Eigenvalue decomposition). For that reason I use some kind of wrapper which allows me to quickly switch the underlying library (I only need a few things like solving systems of equations and Eigenvalue decomposition).

Comment: JEigen does not appear to implement solving sparse matrices [so I did it myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046585/cholmod-in-java/30526005#30526005).

Comment: http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/vector/package-summary.html -- JScience also supports basic math operations on Matrices and Vectors

Comment: https://github.com/BIDData/BIDMat might be a good addition as well.. (though I don't have experience with it)

Answer (score 2):

The interface for COLT gives you a generic OP: [`assign(matrix, function)`](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/DoubleMatrix2D.html#assign%28cern.colt.matrix.DoubleMatrix2D,%20cern.colt.function.DoubleDoubleFunction%29), which you can use to add or subtract matrices and vectors.

As the javadocs for `assign()` says:

> Assigns the result of a function to each cell; 
>   `x[row,col] =function(x[row,col],y[row,col])`.

So by using using an addition function as `function` - you can add matrices.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [la4j](http://la4j.org) library that supports functional programming features as functors. You can use transform() method with manual hi-order function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linearmath/). It is very simple and supply basic matrix operations.

You can add/substract/multiply etc 2d matrixes and vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You may try my newly Java library (compatible with Java 6+) that can be used for all sorts of applications notably for performing multi-threaded matrix calculations (extending JAMA with multi-threading; currently 30% faster than the available open source libraries). You can check it out on GitHub:

https://github.com/b-io/io.barras/tree/master/java/jupiter

Note that each project is independent from each other and is under the very permissive MIT License.