# settings required to call matlab from java (netbeans ide)

Tags: java, matlab, netbeans

I am working on a project that requires me to call the MATLAB functions from Netbeans IDE. Can you please help me with clear instructions as to how to set it up. I am looking for a step by step procedure as to what changes I need to make to the paths etc.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB runs a Java Virtual Machine, but isn't really a library you can just call from Java code, sadly. I believe the closest you'll be able to come is [invoking MATLAB itself programmatically](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/startup-options.html) via system calls in your Java.

However, numerous alternatives to MATLAB exist that you might be able to use. Examples include [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/), [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) and [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815518/java-matrix-libraries).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am talking about invoking the MatlabControl classes. Please refer to the question : "Call matlab from netbeans using matlabcontrol" I need the step by step procedure as to how to set the path variables and where. Hope that helps in better understanding my question. Thanks in advance1

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Matlabcontrol. But you might want to try [Matlab Builder JA](http://www.mathworks.se/products/javabuilder/). Through this you can deploy your Matlab functions in java, and use it like any other java class. The tutorials in the matlab page should be enough for you to understand how it works.