# Simple matrix operations (2D & 3D) using Colt library

Tags: java, matrix, addition, scalar, colt

I want to perform simple matrix operations in my code and I use the Colt library

(see in here: http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/index.html)

I want for example to add/subtract/multiply matrices, add/subtract/multiply/divide a scalar to each cell of a matrix etc...But there seem to be no such functions in this library.

However, I found this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10815643/2866701

How can I use the **assign()** command to perform these simple operations in my code?

Answer (score 4):

Colt provides a more general framework under the `assign()` methods. For example, if you want to add a scalar to each cell of a matrix, you could do the following:

```
double scalar_to_add  = 0.5;
DoubleMatrix2D matrix = new DenseDoubleMatrix2D(10, 10); // creates an empty 10x10 matrix
matrix.assign(DoubleFunctions.plus(scalar_to_add)); // adds the scalar to each cell
```

Standard functions are available as static methods in the `DoubleFunctions` class. Others need to be written by you.

If you want vector addition instead of just adding a scalar value, the second argument of `assign()` needs to be a `DoubleDoubleFunction`. For example,

```
DoubleDoubleFunction plus = new DoubleDoubleFunction() {
    public double apply(double a, double b) { return a+b; }
};    
DoubleMatrix1D aVector = ... // some vector
DoubleMatrix1D anotherVector = ... // another vector of same size
aVector.assign(anotherVector, plus); // now you have the vector sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [la4j](http://la4j.org) (Linear Algebra for Java)? It is easy to use:

```
Matrix a = new Basci2DMatrix(new double[][]{
    { 1.0, 2.0 },
    { 3.0, 4.0 }
});

Matrix b = new Basci2DMatrix(new double[][]{
    { 5.0, 6.0 },
    { 7.0, 8.0 }
});

Matrix c = a.multiply(b); // a * b
Matrix d = a.add(b); // a + b
Matrix e = a.subtract(b); // a - b
```

There is also `transform()` method that is similar to Colt's `assign()`. It can be used as following:

```
Matrix f = a.transform(Matrices.INC_MATRIX); // inreases each cell by 1
Matrix g = a.transform(Matrices.asDivFunction(2)); // divides each cell by 2
// you can define your own function
Matrix h = a.transform(new MatrixFunction {
  public double evaluate(int i, int j, int value) {
    return value * Math.sqrt(i + j);
  }
});
```

But it only works for **2D** matrices.

Comment: I want a library that works for 1D-2D-3D matrices...
And I want also Numeral Analysis, not only Linear Algebra...