# Matrix library in java for complex matrices?

Tags: java, matrix

I have to implement an algorithm which uses a 2D data structure but each cell of the data has to be a further matrix. Which java library should I use? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use arrays containing arrays?

Comment: what about this one: http://la4j.org/

Comment: I have been using JAMA package: http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/

Comment: @verbose-mode what should i use? Like ArrayList or any other data structure?

Comment: @tigran Thanks! I have looked it but I couldn't find any thing in which I can make each cell of array to be a further 2D array..

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use the JAMA Java Matrix Package: http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/

I have used it quite lot some years ago and the ability to create Arrays containing Matrix Objects may suite your needs directly.

Anyhow you may find this 2 questions interesting:

(1) [Java matrix libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815518/java-matrix-libraries?rq=1)
(2) [Performance of Java matrix math libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529457/performance-of-java-matrix-math-libraries?rq=1)

Comment: I looked over the class Matrix of this library but couldn't find how to make arrays containing matrix.. What am I missing there? But Thanks it's good library

Comment: What did you not understand? You make an array of objects and each element points to an object therefor.
Matrix[][] 2d_matrix_to_matrix = new Matrix[10][10];
Matrix[0][0] = new Matrix(int m, int n);

This creates 2d squared array containing each element a matrix of size m x n

Comment: Alright now I'm there that's what I wanted