# Kotlin and generics, implementing abstract generic class with generic array

Tags: arrays, generics, kotlin

I have the following abstract class

`abstract class Vec2t<T : Number>(open var x: T, open var y: T)`

implemented by

`data class Vec2(override var x: Float, override var y: Float) : Vec2t<Float>(x, y)`

So far, everything works just fine

Now, I'd like to do something similar for the matrices, this is at the moment my abstract class

`abstract class Mat2t<T : Number>(open var value: Array<out Vec2t<T>>)`

that should be implemented by

`class Mat2(override var value: Array<Vec2>) : Mat2t<Float>(value)`

But compiler complains on `Array<Vec2>`:

> Error:(8, 32) Kotlin: Type of 'value' doesn't match the type of the overridden var-property 'public open var value: Array> defined in main.mat.Mat2t'

I was told:

- I can't change the type of a `var` property when I override it (but actually I am not really changing it, I am overriding it with a subtype.. is it the same thing?)
- `mat2.value = object : Vec2t<Float>() { ... }` would not be valid, which must not be the case for any subclass of `Mat2t<Float>`

How may I overcome these problems?

Is there a way to have an abstract generic class `Mat2t` with a generic array and implement it with a subtype array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by making your generic parameter a subtype of `Vec2t` instead of a subtype of `Vec2t`'s generic parameter type (`T : Number`):

```
abstract class Mat2t<T : Vec2t<*>>(open var value: List<T>)

class Mat2(override var value: List<Vec2>) : Mat2t<Vec2>(value)
```

---

Note that as you are overriding `var value` you don't need to have it in the abstract class constructor. The same applies for `Vec2t`. e.g.:

```
abstract class Vec2t<T : Number> {
    abstract var x: T
    abstract var y: T
}

class Vec2(override var x: Float, override var y: Float) : Vec2t<Float>()

abstract class Mat2t<T : Vec2t<*>> {
    abstract var value: List<T>
}

class Mat2(override var value: List<Vec2>) : Mat2t<Vec2>()
```

These abstract classes could then even be represented as interfaces instead if that suits you:

```
interface Vec2t<T : Number> {
    var x: T
    var y: T
}

data class Vec2(override var x: Float, override var y: Float) : Vec2t<Float>

interface Mat2t<T : Vec2t<*>> {
    var value: List<T>
}

data class Mat2(override var value: List<Vec2>) : Mat2t<Vec2>
```

Comment: it works, nice. I see you used `List` over `Array`, is there a specific reason? To get covariance? For reference, I am trying to do a port of [this](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_mat2x2.hpp). Cool tip about the interfaces, +1

Comment: @elect Habit I suppose. I almost never use `Array`. Plus I see your `Vec2` is a `data class` which leads me to believe you might want `Mat2` to be a `data class` as well in which case you would have to override `equals` and `hashCode` yourself if you used `Array` (it doesn't implement them) but with a `List` the compiler takes care of it for you. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/36262305/3255152.

Comment: FYI: I'm not sure exactly what you are after but there are various linear algebra / matrix Java libraries out there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815518/java-matrix-libraries. Maybe one of them already meets your use case; maybe not. Enjoy!

Comment: just a kotlin glm porting